# Cloning/Fetching from Git repositories with broken HEAD

Tags: git

I have been tasked with replicating Git repositories from many Git servers in the company as a secondary backup (belt and suspenders, you know).  But what I have found is that there are hundreds of repositories out there where HEAD points to a nonexistent place.  For example:

```
$ git clone --bare somehost:/some/path/to/broken.git
Cloning into bare repository 'broken.git'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 3 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Checking connectivity... done
$ cd broken.git
$ git fetch
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref HEAD
```

One case where this occurs is if the remote repository is entirely empty.  I added code to detect that situation and avoid cloning those, but there are still hundreds left (that is, there are actual commits in those repositories but HEAD does not point to a valid location).

If I had control over the remote servers (which I rarely do), how can this be repaired?  Should I just change HEAD to contain a reference to any valid head that I see under refs/heads?

Now, assuming that repair is out of the question, how can I mitigate?  As far as I can see I have these options:

1. Detect remote repositories with broken HEADs and skip them.
2. When running "git fetch", ignore any errors like the one above.
3. Find some combination of flags which will avoid this problem
4. Leave it as-is, and attempt to force the remote teams to fix their repositories (political solution)

It seems that the potential issue with either 1 or 2 is that I may miss repositories or changes to repositories which actually contain meaningful changes.

FYI: I am running git 1.8.4, and the remote end varies, though the current case in point is 1.7.1.

Comment: OK, someone should hit me with the git manual... using the clone option --mirror option, instead of --bare, seems to get around this problem (that is, both clone and fetch work).

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the remote repository you should check .git/HEAD

I would also run

```
git-show-ref --heads
```

to see if they are empty. It might work to edit .git/HEAD and set it to some existing ref or commit.

Anyway, for the sake of avoiding having to deal with same problem in the future over and over again, I would go for option 4 and try to ask the remote team for help for cloning their repository. They should also be able to advise you which which ref should go into HEAD.

Comment: I don't always have access to the remote repository... some teams give me shell access to their server, others don't.  However, "git show-ref --heads" is very useful and seems like the first step to repairing HEAD:  presumably you could pick a ref (using some to-be-defined heuristic) and stuff that into HEAD.  Or is there a command that will do that bit for you?